# Prevent MUI multi-select from expanding parent flexbox past screen size

Tags: css, flexbox, material-ui

I have a multi-select MUI element, and when I select multiple items on a small screen, the elements make the parent larger, so you would have to scroll to the right to view everything.

How can I fixe this?

```
<Box
  display={"flex"}
  flexDirection={"column"}
  rowGap={3}
  sx={{
    mb: 1,
    px: 2,
  }}
>
  <FormControl>
    <InputLabel id="simple-select-label">
      Job completed by
    </InputLabel>
    <Select
      label="Job completed by"
      name="employeeID"
      multiple={true}
      id="simple-select"
      sx={{
      }}
      required
      value={values.employeeID}
      onChange={(e) => {
        setValues({
          ...values,
          employeeID: e.target.value,
        })
      }}
    >
      {employeesLists?.map((employee) => (
        <MenuItem value={employee.id} key={employee.id}>
          {employee.firstName} {employee.lastName}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Select>
  </FormControl>
</Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I had to use the override nested component strategy: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#1-one-off-customization

I added this to fix the problem, to override the default styles. It can be placed on `<Select>`.

```
                    sx={{
                      '& #simple-select': {
                        whiteSpace: 'normal',
                      },
                    }}
``
```